# Adding "sudo" commands to the bash history of the *target* user

Tags: bash, sudo

Something that's bothered me for many years is that if I want to search my shell history for commands which were run as root, I have to check two different locations:

1. I have to check `/root/.bash_history`.
2. I have to check `/brian/.bash_history` for `sudo` commands.

Is there a solution for bash (or, indeed, *any* shell - I'm willing to switch) which will deposit `sudo` commands into the shell history of the target user?

Comment: You could configure root's .bashrc or .bash_profile so that if $SUDO_USER is non-empty, it sets HISTFILE to point to the user's .bash_history. It would also need to `set  histappend` so it appends rather than overwrites.  This will result in **all** of root's history being appended to the user's history file (unless root's history was also cleared when changing HISTFILE and setting histappend.  clearing it will, of course, make root's history unavailable in that sudo shell)

Comment: e.g. `if [ -n "$SUDO_USER" ] ; then history -c ; set histappend ; HISTFILE="$(getent passwd "$SUDO_USER" | cut -d: -f6)/.bash_history" ; fi`

Comment: @cas Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you run `sudo cat /etc/passwd` for example, your solution wouldn't help. Sudo runs the command directly; it doesn't spawn a brand new bash shell just to run cat, right?

Comment: The simple solution is to run with elevated permissions with the sudo prefix: `sudo command ...`. Then they will be saved in your userID's history. The problem will only appear, when you run as root (for example via `sudo -i`).

Comment: @BrianGordon if you run "sudo command" then that will already be in the user's history.  it's a command run by the user, in their shell.   what you want is ONLY an issue when the the user runs `sudo -i` or `sudo bash` and then starts running commands in the root shell.  THOSE commands will get saved in root's .bash_history.

Comment: actually, i misread your question. i thought you wanted commands run in a root shell to be saved in the user's own history file.    you want almost the opposite of that.  nope, there's no way to do that.

Comment: you could write a wrapper script that grepped for X in both `/root/.bash_history` and `sudo X` in user history files.   or `grep 'sudo.*COMMAND' /var/log/auth.log` (or wherever sudo is logged on your system)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are *operating* in that private unix I-am-root-and-only-user mode, like me. And exactly to avoid a splitting of my personality I log in as root. For the moment - I know it's *a kind of* security problem.

I am so busy installing, testing etc. as a sysadmin, that I cannot present a satisfying login for a user.

And still the bash history can confuse me when I am using several consoles and/or xterms. Only organization I have so far is a small file `hist-keep` with a couple of commands I often use.

> if I want to search **my** shell history for commands which were **run as
>   root**

Do you want to just search, or do you want to "load" the history file, so you can *history-search*?

I just looked up `sudo` yesterday, because of this obscure **sudo vs. pseudo** question. I suddenly realised that "sudo" and "pseudo" are pronounced identically in english, and when you consider "pseudonym" (or "alias") there really is a semantic connection.

Sudo is actually meant to produce a separate tracking of commands. That would be how "root" checks what "brian" (and others) did under pseudonym "root".

But you rather want to *merge* separate histories.

I feel the solution is more a `history -r` of a processed file, and not injecting sudo lines into root's history file.

A first aid solution would of course be a simple function/script that *searches* in these two files, something like

```
grep $1 $root-hist
grep "sudo.*$1" $user-hist
```

Then you can `sudoroot-combigrep "mount"` to get all relevant lines containing "mount". (choose your own easily tab-completeable name)